# Authentication for application using AD authentication via LDAP

Tags: authentication, ldap, weblogic, kerberos

Mobile > SpringMVC API > LDAP 
I have a springmvc application deployed  on weblogic on a unix box  and am using the AD from windows  for LDAP authentication. now i need to integrate with other applications where authentication is required ,i cannot prompt the user to renter the password ,  Since the client is mobile apps , which is the best way to authenticate once for one user for all service request.  For LDAP am using SSL . ? Any suggestions ? Some people referring to use kerberos ticket based service usage , but as i have read it is best for using windows based services ? I have refereed the following sites

http://windowsitpro.com/security/kerberos-active-directory
[Security & Authentication: SSL vs SASL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347304/security-authentication-ssl-vs-sasl)

Answer (score 0):

Kerberos works well with the WebLogic server running on Linux servers.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/idm/weblogic-sso-kerberos-1619890.html

Comment: Hi brian , thanks for your prompt reply . As for my understanding  regarding kerberos , KDC and Ticket generation work well with browser applications on windows environment. My current environment is for a native ios app which connects to our spring rest framework , so can kerberos be used in this scenario. Also i do not require to call any windows services SPN , all i need is the authentication to be passed for another application.

Comment: Ok, WebLogic has what you need on the server side. Configuring the client is a different story. This answer is probably what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813517/single-sign-on-sso-in-ios-7

Comment: good article thanks brian , will check if how we can utilize this solution.